# Mysql error handling for "error 1265"

Tags: mysql

We are using mysql 5.5.16 version. While inserting data into one of the table from the stored procedure we are getting mysql error 1265.But we are unable to identify which column is getting truncated. How can we identify the column which is causing the issue?

Note: if i insert same data using insert statement its not showing any warning or error.

Comment: Doesn't this error tell you which column was truncated?

Comment: Show your Table structure, Query and your code.

Comment: After the insert statement again some sql statements are there because of that after procedure call its not throwing any warning.